# java Process, getInputStream, read newest line only

Tags: java, process, bufferedreader

In the while loop below I want to read only the newest line from Process p's output, ignoring anything else that entered the buffer while the loop was sleeping.  How do I do that?

```
String s;
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = r.exec("SomeContinuousProgram");
myInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

while (true){
  if ((s = myInput.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(s);
  }
Thread.sleep(sleep);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't "skip" to the newest line that was written from the process.  You have to read all lines that came before it.

Split the program into 2 threads.  The main thread will read from the `BufferedReader` and will keep track of what the newest line is.  The other thread will sleep, and then display the newest line.

Comment: thanks.  I realized there would only ever be about 10 lines in the buffer before i got to it again so ijust did this:int c = 0;
      while ((str = marsyasInput.readLine()) != null && c < 20) c++;

Answer (score 0):

```
while (true){
  if ((s = myInput.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(s);
  }
```

This code doesn't make any sense. If `readLine()` returns null, it is the end of the stream, and the only sensible course is to close the stream and exit the reading loop.

Comment: the end of the stream will never come because the process is continuous.  That's why I  just want to grab the newest entry, like a LIFO container.